# Unity: Export options for Windows

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, dependencies, export, game-engine

I have just started using Unity3d for creating 3d and 2d games for the Windows operating system. So, I learnt the basics and created a simple maze game. When I exported the game for Windows operating system in a folder named `Output` it created a executable file in that folder and a Data folder. The Data folder contained many files, folders, dlls, etc. But don't want those all files to come there. Is there a way so that I can export the complete game as a executable or manage the structure of the dependencies on my own? If this not possible then are there any more game engines which will allow me to do this, as I have seen many games having such directory structure.

Another problem that I found was that when I ran the game it first opened a configuration window asking me for the resolution in which I wanted to run the game and other settings. But I don't my game to have that kind of pop-up when I publish it.

So, is there any way that can help me structure my dependencies and remove the configuration window. If you know the answer of any one of these questions then please answer.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way so that I can export the complete game as a executable
>   or manage the structure of the dependencies on my own?

As far as I know, you cannot configure how a Unity app is built.

You could try using a packager application that takes the build directory and generates a single executable file, as described in this question: https://superuser.com/questions/749447/creating-a-single-file-executable-from-a-directory-in-windows . Beware that not every application can be packaged this way, in particular I don't know if these tools work well with Unity applications.

> remove the configuration window

You can avoid the configuration window using `Build Settings -> Player Settings -> Resolution and Presentation -> Display resolution dialog: enable/disable` . Check he following question: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/134444/is-it-possible.html .

Unity also will show a startup screen, which you can customize or remove if you are using the Pro version.

Comment: Your second answer helped me (about the configuration window) Thanks. But in you are first answer you are talking about creating a setup application which will export my game. But I want to export the game such that it should hide all the other reference libraries and only show the main .exe file. In short I want the game to be exported as other famous games, (eg. Counter Strike Condition Zero)

Comment: After building with Unity, you have a directory with the game. You want to build a "single-file executable": this is what the tools mentioned in the link are for.